# symlink created nested symlink

Tags: symlink

I wrote a symlink script for someone on another team to run in a directory I don't have access to, and it seemed to have caused something unexpected.

```
destination_path=/path/to/dest/
source_path=/path/to/src

for dir in first second
do
    # replace existing symlink
    for subdir in {1000..1020}
    do 
        ln -sf $source_path/$dir/$subdir $destination_path/$dir/$subdir
    done
done
```

Before the script was run `path/to/dest/$dir` contains symlinks `1000, 1001, ..., 1020` that's linked to a different set of directories. My script is intended to replace those symlinks with symlinks to `/path/to/src/$dir/$subdir`, but instead of doing that, it seems to have created the symlinks within the existing symlink.

So for example, `/path/to/dest/$dir/1000` used to be a symlink, and after running my script `/path/to/dest/$dir/1000` is still points to the same place but within `/path/to/dest/$dir/1000`, there is a sym link `1000` that points to `$source_path/$dir/$subdir/1000`.

This shouldn't have occurred with my script right? I tried to reproduce this locally with a mocked destination directory structure and I couldn't reproduce this issue.

Edit: upon further research, it seems I should have used `ln -sfn` instead of just `ln -sf`? What is the easiest way to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symlink that points to a directory is (almost always) treated as that directory. In general if you want to update a symlink, remove it and recreate it.

Use a variation of your script like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
destination_path='/path/to/dest/'
source_path='/path/to/src'

for dir in first second
do
    # replace existing symlink
    for subdir in {1000..1020}
    do 
        s="$source_path/$dir/$subdir"
        t="$destination_path/$dir/$subdir"

        [ -d "$t" ] && [ -h "$d/$subdir" ] && echo rm -f -- "$d/$subdir"
        [ -h "$d" ] && echo rm -f -- "$d"
        echo ln -sf -- "$s" "$d"
    done
done
```

Remember to remove all three instances of `echo` when you're happy it's going to do what you need it to do.